# opening modal through button click

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have one basic question on linking the files in codeigniter.
I want to open my modal from the signup button in navigation bar. Since my navigation bar and modal are in different files. I am trying to link them by giving url in href field of button in navbar.

Here is the directory structure:
application

--controllers

----Media.php

--views

----navbar.php

----modals.php

Code of Media.php

```
<?php

 class media extends CI_Controller
 {
  public function view ($page='home')
  {
    $data['title']=$page;
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('media/navbar');
    $this->load->view('media/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
  }
 ?>
```

**Code of navbar.php**

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebCast</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Channel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Favourites</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  >
            <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalsignup" ><a href="media/modals"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModallogin" ><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

**Code of modals.php**

```
<!-- Login Modal -->
<div id="myModallogin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <form class="form-inline" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
         </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Signup Modal -->
<div id="myModalsignup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


         <form class="form-inline" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
          </div>

          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
         </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

How should I give the url here so that on clicking signup, I should be able to open my signup modal?

---

Instead of creating a new question , I am editing this one only after getting the comments?

How can navbar.php get to know that these modal ids exist. And what should be the javascript function used so that on click the signup I can open the modal on the same page?

Comment: You need javascript / ajax for this.

Comment: can't I give any url so that it refers to modals.php file? like the example in this link.. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html while opening a form it gives the url of that page <?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>

Comment: Sure, but then you will always be opening a new page, not a modal on the actual page.

Comment: @ManishKumar keep it load will not make an affect to your system.

Comment: can you point me to the javascript function which can be used here?

Comment: You don't need Javascript unless you don't use bootstrap so what you do I link the model as you would normally within the page and a target of_self and then on the model you could use the controller function as the action of the form just remember to add the controller in you construct